# Can I make QuestDB to add column data to existing rows?

Tags: questdb

I use QuestDB and populate data from ILP messages. I want to see data coming from different sensors on the same row when tags match. For example I send first

```
sensors,location=ny temperature=22 1465839830100400200
```

Table `sensors` is automatically created then with symbol column `location` and double `temperature`. After some time I can have another message like

```
sensors,location=ny humidity=35.2 1465839830100400200
```

If I don't do anything, `humidity` field is simply ignored. If I add humidity field to the table manually as

```
alter table sensors add column humidity double
```

before sending second message I still get back 2 rows, one of which has temperature and empty humidity and another one has humidity and empty temperature

```
| timestamp  | location | temperature | humidty |
| ---------- | -------- | ----------- | ------- |
| 2016-06-13 | ny       |        22.0 |         |
| 2016-06-13 | ny       |             |    35.2 |
```

How can I make temperature and humidity come to the same row even when they are sent independently?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most performant but it's easy:

```
SELECT timestamp, location, max(temperature), max(humidity) from sensors;
```